# Laravel call relation from model in when() conditional clauses

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am creating product filtering and now I have problem when I want to filter product category by name.

I am not sure if is possible to call relation inside when() conditional clauses.

In the product controller, I create:

```
$results = Product::query();
    
// Conditional filter
  
$results->when($request->has('product_code'), function ($q) use ($request) {
  return $q->where('product_code', 'like', '%'.$request->query('product_code').'%');
});

$results->when($request->has('status'), function ($q) use ($request) {
  return $q->where('status', $request->query('status'));
});

$results->when($request->has('price'), function ($q) use ($request) {
  return $q->where('price', $request->query('price'));
});

// Filter by category NAME  
// HERE IS PROBLEM

$results->when($request->has('category_name'), function ($q) use ($request) {
  return $q->category->where('name', $request->query('cat_name'));
});

// I also try 
// This return SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category.name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `products` where `category`.`name` = Apple)

$results->when($request->has('category_name'), function ($q) use ($request) {
  return $q->where('category.name', $request->query('cat_name'));
});


$results = $results->paginate(20);
```

Model:

```
class Product
{
  public function category()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Category', 'id', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for this filtering do this:

```
        $filter = [];
        if($request->product_code!= null)
              array_push($filter, ['product_code', 'like', "%$request->product_code%"]);
        if($request->price)
            array_push($filter, ['price', $request->price]);
        // and so on ...
```

then you have array of conditions, just call where and pass the array:

```
        $results = Product::where($filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about that?

```
$category_ids = Category::where('category_name', $request->query('category_name'))->pluck('id');

$results = Product::select("*")->when($request->has('category_name'), function ($query) use ($request, $category_ids) {
  return $query->whereIntegerInRaw('category_id', $category_ids);
})->get();
```

Comment: This is good i try your first example. But in my solution i need to show list of categories by  passing category name with LIKE clause.

Comment: How about that? -> $category_ids = Category::where('category_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->query('category_name') . '%')->pluck('id');